# How to get resources NOT related by a property using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

How can I use SPARQL to get a set of resources that are NOT related by a property p. For example, if r1, r2, r3 and r4 are resources, :p a property, and we have the following:

- :r1 :p :r2
- :r2 :p :r1

In this case, the subset {r2,r3,r4} and {r1,r3,r4} match that condition (would be the expected result). If I use "FILTER NOT EXISTS resources related by p", I would get {r1,r2,r3,r4}-{r1,r2} = {r3,r4} as result when, for example, {r2,r3,r4} would be another expected result. Can I use other SPARQL filtering mechanism to do this?

Comment: SPARQL queries don't return sets in this way;  they return a series of rows for bindings of variables.  It sounds like you're asking for *sets* of resources such that no pair of them are connected by a particular property.  I'm not sure whether you can do this in SPARQL or not.

Comment: Do you want to require that the resources are related by something else, or just that they are *not* related by p?

Comment: I have deleted the answer `SELECT * WHERE {?s !p ?o}`, as I agree with the comment of @JoshuaTaylor that "i) This requires that ?s and ?o are connected by some property, which might not be the case. (ii) This doesn't enforce that ?s and ?o are not connected by p, just that that they're connected by something that is not p."

Comment: I want to require that the resources are not related by p. For example, If I add the triplets q0 p0 r1 and q0 p0 r2 I would like to know, for example, if resources related to q0 by p0 (r1 and r2), are not related each other by p....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by finding all properties and filtering out matches for `:p`:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER (?p != :p)
}
```